# Calling multiple scopes for dataProvider

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii 1.1.15, and was wondering if there is a way to call multiple scopes?

in my model:

```
public function scopes()
    {
        return array(
            'notPending'=>array(
                    'condition'=>'t.pending!=1',
                ),
             'limit5'=>array(
                    'limit'=>5,
                ),
            'limit6'=>array(
                'limit'=>6,
            )
        );
    }
```

here is my dataProvider in my view:

```
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider(Comment::model()->notPending()->limit5()->findAll());
```

The code above doesn't set the limit to 5, and gives me this error

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getDbCriteria() on a non-object in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/dev/common/lib/yii/framework/web/CActiveDataProvider.php on line 225`

is there a way to do so by using scopes?

Comment: have you defined the scopes in the corresponding model?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin  the scope function above is in my `comment` model class

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled, it should be:

```
Comment::model()->notPending()->limit5()->findAll() // see the last ()
```

[Scopes section](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes)

### Update

From [here](https://coderwall.com/p/cxsxga/yii-cactivedataprovider-with-scopes) seems in ActiveDataProvider you do not need to set `findAll()` at the end:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
 $model = Orders::model()->own()->published();
 $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider($model);
 $this->render('index',array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
 ));
}
```